# What is the difference between Slimline SATA, Slim SATA, and Micro SATA?

Tags: sata

What is the difference between Slimline SATA, Slim SATA, and Micro SATA?

e.g. are there differences in connector?

Answer (score 1):

You have the regular/classic/original SATA connector. That's 7-pin data, 15-pin power.

Micro SATA (Not to be confused with mSATA which is Mini SATA).

Micro SATA  also known as uSATA is from back in the past, when you had 1.8" drives and some (maybe all), had Micro SATA connectors. But 1.8" drives were rare. It was only on those.  The 2.5" drives won out. (And the drives nowadays that are smaller than 2.5" drives, are PCBs, like mSATA, or now, M2 - and M2 isn't necessarily SATA).

Slimline SATA is on optical disk drives.  I think most laptops don't have optical disc drives anymore.

[image]

Slim SATA is regular sized SATA connectors, on a small PCB. It's old and rare.

[image]

---

mSATA is Mini SATA.  (I won't include a pic of it here 'cos the question didn't ask about it..)

From what I understand and i've only been looking into this recently-

There's SATA the communication protocol, and there's SATA the connector. There's also another communication protocol, the PCIe communication protocol. And there's NVMe which was developed after PCIe, and which sits inside / is encapsulated by PCIe. Nowadays where PCIe is in use,  NVMe is. And NVMe necessitates PCIe.  NVMe is faster/better/ a successor to, SATA.

mSATA has been replaced by M2. But an M2 drive isn't necessarily SATA.  And SATA is replaced by NVMe(i.e. PCIe with NVMe).   You can get M2 SATA, or newer, would be M2 NVMe.     M2 is a family of form factors, it specifies connector and physical dimensions.